# Windows 8 travel only selected photos download for storing & printing

Tags: windows-8, bing

Some of the photos on Windows travel (Bing travel) application are too good. I want to store those selected photos for PERSONAL use and print.
Normally right click with Save Image as .... should appear to store the selected file, I do not see that option when I do right click.

Is there any other trick? or its not allowed ?

Answer (score 0):

You can access it with a little trick.

1. Go to the picture, which you want to download.
2. Right-click on the website and choose <kbd>View Source</kbd>.
3. You now see the source-code of the website.
4. Than use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>. Now a search field appears.
5. Type in the following:

   > background-image
6. Now you see the highlighted part in the source-code. Behind this `background-image` you see the `url` to the photo. For example:

   > background-image:url(**/az/hprichbg/rb/PalaceofFineArts_ROW11000533273_1366x768.jpg)**
7. Now just add this part-url to the normal bing-url.

   > http://www.bing.com/az/hprichbg/rb/BonavistaPeninsula_ROW8180731473_1366x768.jpg
8. As you see, I've added the url from the image right behind the bing.com-url.
9. Now you can download the image by right-clicking and downloading it.